# shorter way to run functions using its variables

Tags: php, jquery

**js**

```
var a = 'sun';
var b = 'earth';
var fn = 'some_fn';
$.post('index-pro.php', {fn, a, b}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

I have a lot of code parts like the above, using different variables, but always refering to `index-pro.php` as a target file.

**index-pro.php**

```
if(isset($_POST)){extract($_POST);}

if(isset($fn) && $fn == 'some_fn'){some_fn($a, $b);}
elseif(isset($fn) && $fn == 'another_fn'){another_fn($another_vars);}
elseif(isset($fn) && $fn == 'another_fn'){another_fn($another_vars);}
```

How can I say something like this:

whatever `fn` is set -> run this `fn` using its variables.

Comment: Just use `$fn()`

Comment: @u_mulder, and what about arguments?

Comment: `$fn($a, $b, $c)`

Comment: @u_mulder, but next `fn` have diff vars

Comment: Then pass arguments as subarray in `$_POST`.

Comment: @u_mulder, ok but in that case I again have the construction like - `if some fn is set - run it and use some subset`. That's what I have already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call function using not only it's name, but even by a variable, which stores function name:

```
$fn = 'doStuff';
$a = 2;
$fn($a);
function doStuff($arg)  {
    echo $arg;
}
```

If your arguments are different for different functions then I advise to post data as two items: `funcName` and `funcArguments`, for example:

```
$.post('index-pro.php', {funcName: fn, funcArguments: [a, b]}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

On server side you can do something like (I skip checks and other stuff, just baseline):

```
$fn = $_POST['funcName'];
$arguments = $_POST['funcArguments'];
// with php5.6/php7 you have variadic `...` syntax
$fn(...$arguments);
// or use plain old `call_user_func_array`:
call_user_func_array($fn, $arguments);
```

Comment: I suppose `$fn(...$arguments);` should be `$fn($arguments);`

Comment: No. `...$arguments` is a php feature: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: @puerto, Not sure if you understand risks by calling functions in this way, this is why I recommend you to define your functions using a prefix (for example, `profn_`) and do some checks before calling them (for example, `is_callable($fn) && strpos($fn, 'profn_') === 0`).

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need. Simple idea: provide an array with arguments to a function name: http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php

I didn't tried it out, but this should work:

JS

```
var a = 'sun';
    var b = 'earth';
    var fn = 'some_fn';
    $.post('index-pro.php', {function: fn, args: [a, b]}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
    });
```

PHP

```
$functionName = $_POST['function'];
$args = $_POST['args'];

call_user_func ($functionName,$args)
```